# notepad don't recognize new line character '\n' but works fine with other special character such as tab

Tags: c, io

I am trying to read input string from keyboard and write it into a text file called dFile.txt in my program using fputs(). Since fputs() don't add new line i have explicitly added new line in my code but when i check my output file it did not add any new line. I have added tab "\t" just to cross check if note pad dont recognize any special character but it is working fine with it.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
    char arr[100];
    FILE *dest;
    dest=fopen("dFile.txt","w");
    puts("enter the string");
    while(strlen(gets(arr))>0)
    {
        fputs(arr,dest);
        fputs("\n",dest);
        fputs("\t",dest);                  
    }
    fclose(dest);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you on windows? Did you open the file in regular old nodepad?

Comment: Don't use `gets`. Don't ever use `gets`. It's dangerous, have been obsolete since the C99 standard, and removed completely in the C11 standard.

Comment: @StoryTeller yes i am on windows using cygwin and normal notepad that come inbuilt with the system

Comment: As for your problem, can you please show some example input, and the expected and actual output from that input?

Comment: Right. Then open the file in cygwin's vi or emacs... the new line is there. Notepad is just picky

Comment: When you installed Cygwin, did you tell it to translate newlines? Newlines on Windows and most other non-Windows systems are not the same. On Windows a newline is `"\r\n"`, in POSIX systems (which Cygwin emulates) newline is plain `"\n"`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude tanc its working fine now with "\r\n"

Comment: IMO the only reason to use Notepad is because you have not discovered the free [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) in which you can select the line ending style, and convert one to another, and has all kinds of other stuff.

Comment: @WeatherVane i did have Notepad++ earlier but my system got corrupted and lost all my software. will download and install it now

Comment: Please, be sure to fix that buffer-overflow waiting to happen at `gets()` as others have pointed out as well.

Answer (score 2):

Notepad recognizes a `\r\n` (carriage return, followed immediately by newline) as a line break. Although, some other editors might recognize a `\n` by itself, as do all Unix utilities.

Also (and more importantly): it's [not a good idea to use `gets`](http://c-faq.com/stdio/getsvsfgets.html) for unknown input sources.